# In Azure Logic App, variable (of type array)output is giving as null. How do I get required output

Tags: arrays, json, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have initialize a variable of type array but I am always getting output value as null.

I have used the JSON payload :Log alert with monitoringService = Application Insights from below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-payload-samples

[image]

Here's my array expression :

```
createArray(triggerBody()?['data']?['essentials']?['alertContext']?['condition']?['allof']?[0]?['dimensions']?[0]?['value'])
```

How do I get the actual required output?

The http Output Body schema from which I added the expressions:

```
"body": {
        "schemaId": "azureMonitorCommonAlertSchema",
        "data": {
            "essentials": {
                "alertId": "",
                "alertRule": "",
                "severity": "Sev1",
                "signalType": "Log",
                "monitorCondition": "Fired",
                "monitoringService": "Log Alerts V2",
                "alertTargetIDs": [
             "/subscriptions/"
                ],
                "configurationItems": [
                    "/subscriptions/"
                ],
                "originAlertId": "bb88b50d-3cec-452c-a5d4-xxxxx”,
                "firedDateTime": "2023-XX-XXT",
                "description": “xxxx”,
                "essentialsVersion": "1.0",
                "alertContextVersion": "1.0"
            },
            "alertContext": {
                "properties": {},
                "conditionType": "LogQueryCriteria",
                "condition": {
                    "windowSize": "PT15M",
                    "allOf": [
                        {
                            "searchQuery": "  exceptions \n| where assembly has \”__XXXX\”\n| where timestamp >= ago(1h)\n| summarize errorCount = count() by outerMessage\n| where errorCount >= 1\n| where outerMessage contains \”XXXX\”\n\n”,
                            "metricMeasureColumn": "errorCount",
                            "targetResourceTypes": "['microsoft.insights/components']",
                            "operator": "GreaterThanOrEqual",
                            "threshold": "1",
                            "timeAggregation": "Total",
                            "dimensions": [
                                {
                                    "name": "outerMessage",
                                    "value": "Error Found in XXXX”
                                }
                            ],
                            "metricValue": 12,
                            "failingPeriods": {
                                "numberOfEvaluationPeriods": 1,
                                "minFailingPeriodsToAlert": 1
                            },
                            "linkToSearchResultsUI": "https://portal.azure.comXXX”,
                            "linkToFilteredSearchResultsUI": "https://portal.azure.comXXXX”,
                            "linkToSearchResultsAPI": "https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/XXX”,
                            "linkToFilteredSearchResultsAPI": "https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/XXXx”
                        }
                    ],
                    "windowStartTime": "2023XXXX”,
                    "windowEndTime": "2023XXXX”
                }
            },
            "customProperties": {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to show us the trigger body JSON, far too hard to help without it.

Comment: I have added the http JSON schema.Please check. @Skin

Comment: Thanks but the data is better than the schema.  e.g. the `essentials`, 'allof', etc. part of your expression isn't even shown in the schema.  Can you provide the JSON data from the trigger with masked where need be.

Comment: I have added the trigger body schema.@Skin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll kick yourself when you see it but you specified `essentials` when you didn't need to.  It and `alertContext` are on the same level.

So change your expression to this ...

```
createArray(triggerBody()?['data']?['alertContext']?['condition']?['allof']?[0]?['dimensions']?[0]?['value'])
```

Comment: Can you please flag it as the answer then?  Hot the grey tick next to my answer, that will make it turn green and flag it accordingly.

Comment: Sure..
One more query...if I have multiple values in dimensions for example 10..how can I fetch those in the variable. What changes needs to be done to the current array expression. @Skin

Comment: You’d need to change your approach to loop over them all and append each value to an array variable. There’s an operation for the append.